# Good way to do multi-word synonym search

Tags: solr, synonym

All:

I want to do a multi-word synonym search, to get search to work like:

```
"small dog" means puppy 
"cute small cat" may refer to kitten
```

**[1]** I do not know how to define those multi-word phrase in synonyms.txt to make it work. **Could anyone ell me how to define those phrase in synonyms.txt**

**[2]** Another thing is: Once the synonym can work, how can I match both "small dog" and "little dog" which have similar meaning with puppy? Like:

```
"a small dog" also means "small dog" means puppy 
"cute cat" may refer to "cute small cat" may refer to kitten
```

( I mean if there is any way we can **collapse the phrase which has similar meaning and words into the synonym phrase which is in the synonym list**)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be done very easily.

In synonyms file you need to write something like this:

```
small dog => puppy
```

According to second question:

```
a small dog => puppy
little dog => puppy
```

=> in Solr synonyms file means 1-way synonym, if you want to to have 2-way synonyms, you need to list them with comma as a delimeter.

For more info about synonyms in Solr - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory